# Why github contribution is hidden?

Tags: git, github

As the title said github my contribution is hidden.
Last commit is :
    f*****.*****@epitech.fr committed yesterday

And I even do not appear on contributors. 
I have two email on my github setting "f*****.*****@epitech.fr" and "f**********@gmail.com"

I thought "Okay github can't match my epitech email anyway" so I try some commands found only but none of them worked.

If someone had that issue or can help me it would be great.

Also I already have a service like github named blih at my origin. So to add my project on github I did a remote.

https://github.com/Florian-crg/Epicture_2020/graphs/contributors

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are referring to the contribution graph of your repository:

To view your contributions on the contributions graph, GitHub needs to associate them with your account.

To do so, add the email ID you used for making your commits to your GitHub account (under Settings).

---

If you are referring to viewing contributions in your profile, the same as above should apply to your specific case. For other situations, you can refer to the [GitHub help page](https://help.github.com/en/github/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-profile/why-are-my-contributions-not-showing-up-on-my-profile).

Comment: I already add my email to my setting I confirmed it and I checked my email with git config by command line :/ . I will check your link